# How to avoid \tikzexternalize to redo all figures, if a figure is added in between

Tags: tikz-external

I'm using the `\tikzexternalize` command to generate the tikzpictures in seperate folders with the name according to the chapter. Therfore i use the command
`\def\useexternalfile#1{\tikzsetnextfilename{#1-output}\input{\csname tikzexternal@filenameprefix\endcsname#1.tikz}}`
in the preamble. The code causes the chapter name to be saved in the name of the tikz file. However, all PDFs of the tikfiles will have a continuous counter from 0 to the last graph, no matter which chapter they are in. If I insert an additional graph in the text, all graphs inserted after this (new) graph will be recreated. Since the document is very long, this also takes a long time. How can I achieve that only the newly inserted graph is created, or at least only those in the same chapter.
Thank you very much

Comment: You could use \include for each chapter and \includeonly to select the current chapter.  At the least, it will only update the tikzpictures in the current chapter.  Not sure how it will affect tikz internal counters, but I suspect that each chapter will restart at 1 so long as you only do one chapter at a time.  It will never be as efficient as using standalone manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by adding a suffix to the figure name. \tikzexternalize[figure name=_plot_sec\thesubsection_no] . No only the figures in the specific subsection, where the new figure is added, are redone. :)